# NSManagedObjectControllers read only access on another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am selecting some Core Data entries and sorting them. This is straight forward enough but because of the calculations in the sort by distance I wanted to put it in an alternate thread. I did that the usual way by making a new NSManagedObjectController for the other thread by adding the code within the `#ifdef THREADS` sections below.

Now I can do my fetch, then my sorting and organizing, without slowing the user interface and the table will be updated when ready.

But, since I am doing my fetch in the local managed object context, my fetched objects are not valid on my main thread - in fact they disappear out of my table view cells.

So, my questions are: 1) would it be OK to use the main managed object context, since I am only reading, and not create a local context at all? 2) should I go through and re-fetch all the objects from the main managed object context on the main thread using the ObjectID values from the search managed object context objects after sorting and organizing? 3) should I do my fetch on the main managed object context with `PerformBlockAndWait` but then keep the sort and organize with the returned objects on the `searchQ` thread? 4) something else I have not thought of?

```
- (void) fetchShopLocations {
#ifdef THREADS
    dispatch_queue_t searchQ = dispatch_queue_create( "searchQueue", NULL );
    dispatch_async( searchQ, ^{
#endif
        NSError *error;

#ifdef THREADS
        // Make a managed object context that can be not on the main thread
        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
#else
        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = self.managedObjectContext;
#endif

        // Get the array of locations sorted by distance
        NSArray *locations = NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: NSStringFromClass([Shop class])];
        // No sort descriptors since I cannot sort on things not in the database

        NSArray *locations = [context executeFetchRequest: request error: &error];
        if( !locations ) {
            NSLog( @"Shop fetch error: %@", error );
            return;
        }
        locations = [locations sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult( Shop *loc1, Shop *loc2 ) {
                    double dist1 = [loc1 distanceFromLatitude: self.referenceLatitude andLongitude: self.referenceLongitude];
                    double dist2 = [loc2 distanceFromLatitude: self.referenceLatitude andLongitude: self.referenceLongitude];
                    if( dist1 < dist2 )
                            return NSOrderedAscending;
                    else if( dist1 > dist2 )
                            return NSOrderedDescending;
                    return [[loc1 name] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: [loc2 name]];
        }];

        NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 5];
        NSMutableDictionary *section;
        NSMutableArray *rows;

        section = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: 2];
        rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: locations.count];
        __block double sectionLimitUserUnits = 5.0;
        __block double sectionLimitKilometers;
        if( self.userUnits == LocationDistanceUnitsMiles )
              sectionLimitKilometers = sectionLimitUserUnits * KILOMETERS_PER_MILE;
        else  sectionLimitKilometers = sectionLimitUserUnits;
        [section setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Within %g", sectionLimitUserUnits] forKey: kSectionHeaderTitleKey];
        [locations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^( Shop *loc, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop ) {
            double distance = [loc distanceFromLatitude: self.referenceLatitude andLongitude: self.referenceLongitude];
            if( distance > self.maxDistance ) {
                *stop = YES;
            } else {
                while( distance > sectionLimitKilometers ) {
                    [section setValue: [rows copy] forKey: kRowKey];
                    [sections addObject: [section copy]];
                    [section removeAllObjects];
                    [rows removeAllObjects];

                    sectionLimitUserUnits += 5.0;
                    if( self.userUnits == LocationDistanceUnitsMiles )
                          sectionLimitKilometers = sectionLimitUserUnits * KILOMETERS_PER_MILE;
                    else  sectionLimitKilometers = sectionLimitUserUnits;
                    [section setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Within %g", sectionLimitUserUnits] forKey: kSectionHeaderTitleKey];
                }
                [rows addObject: loc];
            }
        }];
        [section setValue: [rows copy] forKey: kRowKey];
        [sections addObject: [section copy]];

#ifdef THREADS
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
#endif
            self.sections = sections;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
#ifdef THREADS
        });
    });
    dispatch_release( searchQ );
#endif
}
```

Because of the non-deterministic nature of threading conflicts I know I can't rely on just testing what appears to work in the simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) would it be OK to use the main managed object context, since I am only reading, and not create a local context at all?

No. Someday, something will access the main managed object context at the same time with the fetch and it will be a headache. (I have encountered a deadlock doing this.)

> 2) should I go through and re-fetch all the objects from the main managed object context on the main thread using the ObjectID values from the search managed object context objects after sorting and organizing?

Not *all* the objects, since you are already using a table view, you only need to re-fetch the objects that will be displayed in the table. And re-fetching the objects from the main thread using ObjectID is the correct thing to do.

> 3) should I do my fetch on the main managed object context with `PerformBlockAndWait` but then keep the sort and organize with the returned objects on the `searchQ` thread

This is another option, but you need to understand *really well* how it works. The approach you are doing is actually simpler.

> 4) something else I have not thought of?

You can avoid sorting the array in code by making a query that return the locations ORDER BY distance. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949219/702461).

Comment: Thanks @honganhkhoa, as for #4, I wanted to do the distance calculation as an Sqlite user defined function but my data is in Core Data and I get completely stuck at the "add this line immediately after you call sqlite3_open" part of the description. Core Data does all the opening, etc. I started contemplating opening the underlying Sqlite file directly but it started getting pretty warty.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you keep all operations on a NSManagedObjectContext within a single thread or a serial queue. With iOS5 you can create NSManagedObjectContext's with a private queue concurrency type and handle all operations in the performBlock method on that context. So, to answer question 1, only access your NSManagedObjectContext and the associations with it in the thread or queue associated with it. Don't access it in the main queue if it was created for another. It'll give you headaches down the road!

Question 2 is the best approach. Doing the hard work in the background and then fetching only what you need on the main thread is a great, safe way to handle what you're trying to do.

Question 3: If your main managed object was created with the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType concurrency type then you don't need to do performBlock: or performBlockAndWait: while on the main thread. You'd only need to use those if you needed to do something from a background thread.

Also, I'd strongly recommend [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It's made my life working with core data a lot easier, and significantly reduced the amount of boilerplate code I've had to write to get simple things done.

~James

Comment: Thanks James Richard. I spent a lot of time looking over MagicalRecord... it looks great I wish I knew about it before I started my project! I have too many lines of code written to be comfortable trying to switch to it now.